# Get underlying data in R(ggplotly2)

Tags: r, d3.js, kibana

I have developed some graphs in R using ggploty2 package. 
there are methods to show data on mouse hover. I wonder if there is any way to get the underlying data on this event.

Ex: I have a bar chart with sum of sales in each months of all products.

if i mouse hove i can see the number of sales of that month, but i want all the sales details of that in a different place/div.

is it possible to it in D3.js/R or any visualization tool.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`plotly{}` has a function to convert `ggplot` objects to interactive plots using the `plotly.js` library. Very simple example:

```
install.packages(plotly)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg))
p

ggplotly(p)
```

There's many other tools for interactive plots using various `.js` libraries [here](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_leaflet.html), but `plotly` is probably most convenient if you've already got `ggplot` objects.

Comment: I have already tried this. with this i am able to get data on mouse hover. what I'm trying to do is "if a bar count is 10, I want all the 10 records". this can be done in Tableau, but I'm trying to do it in d3/google plot/R

Comment: `dygraphs{}` will show data in the top right portion of the graph, but has no `ggplot` converter